# there is a error when use Asymptote draw figures

Tags: asymptote

I draw a figure by Asymptote, code as:

```
 import tube;
 import graph3;

 size(7.5cm,0);

 currentprojection=perspective(7,10,3);
 currentlight=light(8,10,2);

 real a=5;
 path3 g1=(a,-a,0)--(a,a,0)..(0,a,a)..(-a,a,0)
 --(-a,-a,0)--(0,-a,a)--cycle;

 draw(tube(g1,scale(a/10)*unitcircle),red);

 limits((-a,-a,-a),(1.5a,1.5a,1.5a));
 xaxis3("$x$",Arrow3);
 yaxis3("$y$",Arrow3);
 zaxis3("$z$",Arrow3);
```

There is a error, first, if I don't have the "$x$", "$y$", "$z$", in the last three line, it will run well,[image]

But have these character, it will turn error. I'm a new, so I don't know why it happend and how to solve it.

I using windows 7 64bit, TexLive 2014 latest.

the error is [image]

Comment: Is that asympte or a previewing programme giving that error? Your example compiles fine using `asy` provided by an up to date TeX Live 2014 installation on Linux. Plus the generated eps previews fine in GV on Linux. So you might want to give some more information about your system and exactly where it fails?

Comment: Hello. Can you precise the Ghostscript version? In fact there is a bug, Asymptote does not use the right output with the latest Ghostscript. You can have more information here http://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/bugs/180/. There are similar messages on Asymptote forum (and from some French users).

Comment: I using windows 7 64bit, TexLive 2014 latest. Thanks.

Comment: I am not used with Texlive under Windows. I do not know if Ghostscript is installed through Texlive or not. For your problem (which is now reported by different users on Windows) the question is the version of Ghostscript. With version >= 9.14 the epswrite device (used by Asymptote to create 3D Label) is deprecated and replaced by eps2write. You can see this on your second screenshot. Archlinux provides a patched Asymptote version (it consists in replacing epswrite by eps2write in label.in). For Windows users, please wait for a new Asymptote version or downgrade Ghostscript.